# Exception with a simple binary code converter

Tags: java, arrays, exception, binary

I've got a problem with my simple binary code converter in Java (applet):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class dual_convert extends Applet implements ActionListener{
  TextField dual;
  TextField decimal;
  Button dual_b;
  Button decimal_b;
  Label dual_l;
  Label decimal_l;
  int decimal_i;
  String dual_s [];
  int dual_i;
  int decimal_e;

  public void init() {
    setLayout(null);

    dual = new TextField();
    dual.setBounds(90,10,100,25);
    add(dual);

    decimal = new TextField();
    decimal.setBounds(90,40,100,25);
    add(decimal);

    decimal_l = new Label("Decimal:");
    decimal_l.setBounds(10,40,80,25);
    add(decimal_l);

    dual_l = new Label("Binary:");
    dual_l.setBounds(10,10,80,25);
    add(dual_l);

    dual_b = new Button ("Convert");
    dual_b.setBounds(200,10,80,25);
    add(dual_b);
    dual_b.addActionListener(this);

    decimal_b = new Button ("Convert");
    decimal_b.setBounds(200,40,80,25);
    add(decimal_b);
    decimal_b.addActionListener(this);

  }

  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==decimal_b) {
      decimal_i = Integer.parseInt(decimal.getText());  
      int ih = 0;
      dual.setText("");
      while (decimal_i>0) {
        dual.setText((decimal_i % 2)+dual.getText());
        decimal_i = decimal_i / 2; 
        ih++;
      }    
    }

    if (e.getSource()==dual_b) {
      dual_s = dual.getText().split("");
      dual_i = dual_s.length;
      decimal.setText("");
      for (int i=0;dual_i>0;dual_i--) {
        decimal_e = decimal_e + (Integer.parseInt(dual_s[dual_i]) * 2^i); 
        i++;
      } 
      decimal.setText(decimal_e+"");       
    } 
  }
}
```

It throws this exception by pressing Convert Binary to Decimal:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8   at
>   dual.actionPerformed(dual.java:65)    at
>   java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)   at
>   java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

For the binary-->decimal conversion I use this system (Is there even an other?):

100101 = [ ( 1 ) × 25 ] + [ ( 0 ) × 24 ] + [ ( 0 ) × 23 ] + [ ( 1 ) × 22 ] + [ ( 0 ) × 21 ] + [ ( 1 ) × 20 ]

100101 = [ 1 × 32 ] + [ 0 × 16 ] + [ 0 × 8 ] + [ 1 × 4 ] + [ 0 × 2 ] + [ 1 × 1 ]

100101 = 3710

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

EDIT: After Talas post there is a new exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""     at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  at
>   dual_convert.actionPerformed(dual_convert.java:64)    at
>   java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)   at
>   java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 for (int i=0;dual_i>0;dual_i--) {
    decimal_e = decimal_e + (Integer.parseInt(dual_s[dual_i - 1]) * 2^i); 
    i++;
  }
```

You should use `dual_s[dual_i - 1]` instead of `dual_s[dual_i]` since `dual_i = dual_s.length;` and array indexes start with `0`

Comment: We're moving forward... new exception:
[http://pastebin.com/bmqf8SrE](http://pastebin.com/bmqf8SrE)

Comment: What about this question? Have I fixed your exception?

Comment: The old one, yes, but with it a new one came.

Comment: Should I make a new post with the new exception, because I can accept only one answer as right.

Comment: Yes, since there is another exception and problem could be in totally different place. First, try to find it yourself, if no success - post it in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You have both the class and a textfield called dual. I am a bit surprised this compiles, but that could be the problem.

Comment: You're rigth, that's odd, but it works, even with an other class name.
//EDIT I've changed the code in the post.